# Eclipse: Notification when methods are renamed? before/after

Tags: methods, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am looking for an event or notification that enables me to react in my Eclipse-Plugin when methods of a (java)classes are changed (renamed or removed/added). 
I am particularly interested in the IJavaElement representation of the method that is changed.

Does some kind of event exists that provides me with this kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my plugin.xml

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants">
  <renameParticipant
        class="bookmark.renameparticipant.JavaElementRenameParticipant"
        id="bookmark-pp.bookmark.renameParticipant1"
        name="name">
     <enablement>
        <with
              variable="element">
           <or>
              <instanceof
                    value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit">
              </instanceof>
              <instanceof
                    value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType">
              </instanceof>
              <instanceof
                    value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IMethod">
              </instanceof>
              <instanceof
                    value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IField">
              </instanceof></or>
        </with>
     </enablement>
  </renameParticipant>
```

and my source of my rename participant:

I set a breakpoint in the init-method of the participant, but if I use CTRL+2+R in Eclipse not even the init is called:

```
@Override
    protected boolean initialize(Object element) {

        if (!(element instanceof IJavaElement)) {
            return false;
        }

        oldHandleId = ((IJavaElement) element).getHandleIdentifier();
        detectElementType((IJavaElement) element);

        newHandleId = generateNewHandleId(oldHandleId);

        if (!initSuccessful()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Of course local variables are not being included since you don't have them in your plugin.xml.  You need to add an instanceof test for `org.eclipse.jdt.core.ILocalVariable`.

Comment: I am not interest in local variables, but only in elements belonging to a class definition (private, protected, package or public).
There are 2 ways of renaming. The 1st one is by using your proposed extension point and the refactoring of Eclipse, that works well. The 2nd way is using the source file wide rename feature.
The 2nd way does not automatically update references on the renamed element in other source files, but only in the currently opened one. Your extension points covers the 1st way, but not the 2nd one.
How do I get a rename notification if a method is renamed by CTRL+2 then R?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for rename participants.  See the extension point `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipant`.

You get a chance to hook into a refactoring and you get a callback when the refactoring starts through the `checkConditions` method as well as when it ends through the `createChange` method.

Comment: Thank you. If I rename an IMethod, IType etc. via Package-Explorer (F2 or Rename in context menu) it works. If I use CTRL+ALT+R in the source file it works too. Is there are way to catch the rename if it is only a local rename within the source file CTRL+2+R - the latter kind of rename seems not to trigger the renameParticipant.

Comment: This should be no problem, as long as you set up your participant properly.  Ask another question, paste in the extension as well as the relevant part of the rename participant java class.

Comment: don't know what I am doing wrong, but my rename participant is not called if an element is renamed by CTRL+2+R...